# Handle Google api calendar removed access

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using this [googleapis nodejs client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) for calendar, and everything works perfect except that if I remove access from google account security settings, 
 calendar is still connected. Is there any method to check for removed access from google account? How to handle those cases?

Comment: I dont think i understand the question what account is still connected?

Comment: Yes, account is still connected

Comment: how do you know?

Comment: I have access using my token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user runs your application the first time they are presented with a consent form.  Which asks them to grant permission for your application to access their Google calendar data.   From this point on when ever your application runs the user may have to login again but they will not have to grant your application permission.  If you have a refresh token you will be able to use that when ever you like to request a new access token.   the access token will be valid for one hour.

Now if you request a new access Token as stated its valid for one hour.  This is true even if the user goes to [Google Account security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) for their account and removes the consent for an application access their data.

Your still going to be able to access their data while any access tokens you have currently are valid.  If the user tries to use your application again they will have to consent permission.  If you try to use the refresh token it will no longer work.

Access tokens work for one hour they are not reauthorized during that time its assumed that they are valid.  (This may in fact depend upon the scope and API in question and how googles policy server works.)

[access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-10) are designed to be self contained permission systems.  As long as you have an access token for the correct scope most apis assume that you have access.  However in the event this method is accessing critical data then they may have a policy server setup.  This server could be doing an extra check on an access token to ensure that the user still has access even though they have a valid access token. However doing this can be very time consuming and resource heavy as reevaluating every call to ensure that the user still has access. It kind of defeats the purpose of having access tokens that are valid for an hour in the first place.

Comment: Try to use the refresh token if it works then the user has granted you access if it doesn't then they probably removed you.  This should be instantiations from when the user removed you.    The access token will expire an hour after you requested it it will be unaffected by the user removing your access.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing this answer. It originally stated that access tokens will survive for one hour, even if the user revokes permission. This is not true. If a user revokes permission then any access tokens are immediately (well within a minute or so) revoked.

Comment: I have taken the  liberty  to revert it back because that is not true about all scopes and APIs I suggest you test it.

Comment: @pinoyyid don't edit other people's answers to match your own ideas. Either leave a comment or write your own answer. Raise another flag if it happens again DalmTo.

Comment: The original post is factually incorrect as explained in my comment. This is not an "idea" it's a fact. I did test it and the behaviour is exactly as I expected. Steps to recreate: obtain an access token. Get drive.about. observe correct response. Revoke permission. Wait 1 minute for CRL propagation. Get drive.about. observe 401 error.